# SQL Sentry returning to old view

Tags: sql, sql-server

Now that SQL Sentry has become a free product, it has all nifty features pro version had before, such as capturing every single statement that has been executed, even variable assignments and etc. Which look like this:

[image]

But having all of this adds so much noise and it becomes impossible to read execution plans properly. Previously it was showing only actual sql executions. Screenshot taken from web:

[image]

How do I revert to this view in latest SQL Sentry version?